# silverlight componentone combobox binding issue

Tags: silverlight, binding, combobox, componentone, c1flexgrid

I have to display combobox in silverlight componentone flexgrid. but when i am applying valueconvertor to that column it works and display combobox, but when i select any value from combobox and select same column from other row then it automatically select the same value which is selected in previous row.